# keras: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'

Tags: python, keras, attention-model

This part is Input and Embedding,then get the output through BIGRU

```
u_in = L.Input(name="user", shape=(10,), dtype="int32")
        '''embeding'''
        u = u_in
        # mask = self.mask_layer(x)
        u = self.embedding_layer(u)  
        hidden_size= 128
        u_gru = Bidirectional(GRU(hidden_size, return_sequences=True))(u)
        u_att = Attention_layer()(u_gru)
        print(u_att)
```

attention layer

```
class Attention_layer(Layer):
    def __init__(self,
                 W_regularizer=None, b_regularizer=None,
                 W_constraint=None, b_constraint=None,
                 bias=True, **kwargs):
        self.supports_masking = True
        self.init = initializers.get('glorot_uniform')
        self.W_regularizer = regularizers.get(W_regularizer)
        self.b_regularizer = regularizers.get(b_regularizer)

        self.W_constraint = constraints.get(W_constraint)
        self.b_constraint = constraints.get(b_constraint)

        self.bias = bias
        super(Attention_layer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        assert len(input_shape) == 3
        self.W = self.add_weight(name='att_weight',shape=(input_shape[-1], input_shape[-1],),
                                 initializer=self.init,
                                 regularizer=self.W_regularizer,
                                 constraint=self.W_constraint   )

        if self.bias:
            self.b = self.add_weight((input_shape[-1],),
                                     initializer='zero',
                                     name='{}_b'.format(self.name),
                                     regularizer=self.b_regularizer,
                                     constraint=self.b_constraint)

        super(Attention_layer, self).build(input_shape)
    def compute_mask(self, input, input_mask=None):
        # do not pass the mask to the next layers
        return None

    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        uit = K.dot(x, self.W)
        if self.bias:
            uit += self.b
        uit = K.tanh(uit)
        a = K.exp(uit)
        if mask is not None:
            a *= K.cast(mask, K.floatx())
        a /= K.cast(K.sum(a, axis=1, keepdims=True) + K.epsilon(), K.floatx())
        print(a)
        print(x)
        weighted_input = x * a
        print(weighted_input)
        return K.sum(weighted_input, axis=1)
    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], input_shape[-1])
```

I don't know how to solve my problem, my input is <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>, after BIGRU processing, input into this layer, and then there is a problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I'm guessing that the issue is in ```self.W = self.add_weight((input_shape[-1], input_shape[-1],),``` where you put a ```(input_shape[-1], input_shape[=1],)``` as the first parameter.   Is this valid?  Afaik, the first parameter is the name, the second is the shape.  Did you want ```shape=(input_shape[-1], input_shape[-1])```?

Comment: I first tried to modify ‘name=’ to the first parameter and still reported an error

Comment: `u_gru = Bidirectional(GRU(hidden_size, return_sequences=True))(u)
 u_att = Attention_layer()(u_gru)`

I see`self.add_weight(name='att_weight',shape=(input_shape[-1], input_shape[-1],) ）` )given by the code on the Internet, I don't know how to modify it

Comment: Please include that code in your post and not in the comments.

Comment: I re-updated my code, please help me find the problem, thanks

Comment: What about the ```self.b = self.add_weight((input_shape[-1],),```  one?  If you update that, do you still have that error?